# Unable to highlight line if time is greater than 15 minutes in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to highlight a result line in an SSRS report if a value is greater than 15 minutes.

I have tried different variations of the line below but it still isn't recognizing anything greater than 15 minutes.

Thanks in advance!

Here are a few different things I have tried:

```
=IIF((Fields!ACTUAL_DEPARTURE.Value-Fields!PLANNED_DEPARTURE.Value)> "00:15:00", "Yellow", "Transparent")
=IIF((Fields!ACTUAL_DEPARTURE.Value-Fields!PLANNED_DEPARTURE.Value)> 15, "Yellow", "Transparent")
=IIF((Fields!ACTUAL_DEPARTURE.Value-Fields!PLANNED_DEPARTURE.Value)> "15:00", "Yellow", "Transparent")
```

Comment: Perhaps the [`DATEDIFF` function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337092(v=sql.100).aspx) better suits your needs?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
= Iif(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Fields!ACTUAL_DEPARTURE.Value, Fields!PLANNED_DEPARTURE.Value) > 15 , "Yellow", "Transparent")
```